# Filevault - Wordpress website issue

Tags: imac, filevault, encryption

I decided to try to turn on Filevault; the problem is I can NOT log into my Wordpress websites back end.

It keeps saying that my passwords are wrong.

I go to another Mac that has Filevault turned OFF and try and I get in with no problems.  Is Filevault messing up with the data?

It's saying it will take 2 days to encrypt.  I'm ready to just erase the damn hard drive and start all over again.

Comment: I don't see a good reason why enabling FV and your Wordpress login issues should be related. You don't run your website backend on the Mac currently encrypting its HD, I assume? Did you try with a different browser?

Comment: I've seen WordPress behave badly on some machines after a while. On my iPad, for instance, I often can't log in through .../wp-admin, but can through another login page. Likely something's off with your browser's cache and/or cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I run many a wordpress site and have turned filevault on and off without issue. I can't think of how the two would get in eachother's way, but perhaps try changing the keys in `wp-config.php` to force expiry of any stale sessions/cookies? [This page](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/) generates new ones for you.